# How can i get html-escaped JSON data of unescaped JSON content

Tags: javascript, json

How can i get the html-escaped JSON data of this

```
{ "timestamp":  1345719094, 
  "callback": "https://www.example.com/cloudinary_cors.html",
  "signature": "7ac8c757e940d95f95495aa0f1cba89ef1a8aa7a", 
  "api_key": "1234567890" }
```

for using it like this :

```
<input name="file" type="file" 
       class="cloudinary-fileupload" data-cloudinary-field="image_upload" 
       data-form-data=" ... html-escaped JSON data ... " ></input>
```

How can i do it in HTML and javascript ?

In advance thanks.

Comment: Do you want to *write* or *read* the attribute value?

Comment: I need to write it in my HTML on the data-form-data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how much you want to encode use either:

```
    element.setAttribute('data-form-data', encodeURI(data));
```

or

```
    element.setAttribute('data-form-data', encodeURIComponent(data));
```

didn't include a JSON.stringify, but you could do that on your data first.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reference to the DOM element in JavaScript, you can do it like this:

```
element.setAttribute('data-form-data', JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: How to define data : like this : var = { "timestamp":  1345719094, 
  "callback": "https://www.example.com/cloudinary_cors.html",
  "signature": "7ac8c757e940d95f95495aa0f1cba89ef1a8aa7a", 
  "api_key": "1234567890" };

Comment: @McbJam: Yes, like that, but with `var data =` rather than just `var =` and without the semicolon after the `.html"`.